# Return a result in descending order

Tags: python

Teachers of Horizon Academy Public School collect the names of those students who are going to participate in the Mathematics exhibition, that is to be held in a week's time.  They have collected all the names and now, they want to store all the names into a system, in the descending order of the length of the names.  This means, the longest name should get stored first, followed by the name that is shorter than the previous, and so on.   Can you help the teachers to perform this task easily by creating a program in Python?

Note:  The number of names specified must be positive, else the program should display the message "Invalid Input" terminate the program.

Input format:
Input consists of an integer that corresponds to the number of names followed by the names.

Output Format:
Print the name list sorted by the names' length, if name length are equal sort based on alphabetical order in descending order as shown in the sample input and output.

Sample Input 1:
Enter the number of names :
5
Enter the names:
William
James
Ella
Lily
Jackson

Sample Output 1:
The sorted name list is:
William
Jackson
James
Lily
Ella

### Sample Input 2:
Enter the number of names:

Sample Output 2:
Invalid Input

Sample Input 3:
Enter the number of names :
3
Enter the names:
Lily
Jack
Lucy

Sample Output 3:
The sorted name list is:
Lucy
Lily
Jack

**Above is the question and below is my code.**

```py
n=int(input("Enter the number of names:\n"))

l=[]

if n>0:

    print("Enter the names:")

    for i in range(n):

        l.append(input())

    print("The sorted name list is:")

    l.sort(key=len,reverse=True)

    for i in l:

        print(i)

else:

    print("Invalid Input")
```

I can't seem to figure out why I can't sort it alphabetically. Any suggestion? For example if my input is "Lily, Jake, Lucy", I want it to display the result "Lucy, Lily, Jake"

Comment: I would recommend putting the code in the question.

Comment: Can you please explain why you're using `key=len` if you wanted alphabetical ordering? And why does it seem you're trying to use bubble sort?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think you're misunderstanding the behavior of the `<list>.sort()` method, here you don't need to use the `key` parameter:

```py
number_of_names = int(input('Number of names: '))

names = list()

if number_of_names > 0:

    print('Enter the names:')
    for _ in range(number_of_names):
        names.append(input())
    
    names.sort(reverse=True)
    for name in names:
        print(name)
```

Key isn't useful there, it can be if you want to modify each key, for example, if I want to sort my items after applying a specific transformation:

```py
l = ["tato", "taty", "tyta", "tate"]

# if I want to sort this list based on the  last character of each items
l.sort(key=lambda x: x[-1])
# l = ['tyta', 'tate', 'tato', 'taty']
```

Actually this parameter, will be very useful when you have a list of dicts and you want to sort it based on a parameter:

```py
users = [{"name": "Jack", "age": 22}, {"name": "John", "age": 16}]
users.sort(key=lambda user: user['age']) # sort the users by age
```

Comment: I tried your way of taking out the key parameter and still could not get it right. I edited my question which I hope will make it easier for you to understand the question. Thanks for answering my questions by the way, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @TohToh okay I see if you want to display your list as string separated by commas, you'll just have to put `print(','.join(names)) `

Answer (score 1):

The issue in the code is that you are specifying a key to sort. It is currently sorting by length in decending order. I tried this and it gets the result you are looking for:

```
people = ['Lily', 'Lucy', 'Jack']

people.sort(reverse=True)

print(people)
```

Read more about `sort()` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_sort.asp)

Answer (score 0):

use `reverse = True` while using `sort` method

```
l = list(["Lilly", "Lucky", "Jack"])

l.sort(key=lambda x: x, reverse=True)
print(l)
```

Updated ans:

`key = len` doesn't make sense

```
n=int(input("Enter the number of names:\n"))

l=[]

if n>0:

    print("Enter the names:")

    for i in range(n):

        l.append(input())

    print("The sorted name list is:")

    l.sort(reverse=True)

    for i in l:

        print(i)

else:
    print("Invalid Input")
```

### Output:

```
$ python3 test.py

Enter the number of names:
3
Enter the names:
Lilly
Lucky
Jack
The sorted name list is:
Lucky
Lilly
Jack
```

Comment: I tried changing my key to lambda as well but that just kind of made it worse.  I edited my question which I hope will make my question more understandable. Thanks for your responds by the way I really appreciate it.